# Работа с массивом checkbox'ов

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой записи данных от checkbox'ов в бд, точнее - при значении checked - данные записываются в бд, а вот снять флажок не получается

```
$cheked = ($option_row_switch['value'] == 1 ? 'checked' : '');
   echo '<input type="checkbox" name="parameter_value1['.$option_row_switch['option_id'].']" '.$cheked.' />';

if (isset($_POST['parameter_value1']))
   {
    foreach($_POST['parameter_value1'] as $option_id => $value1)
    {
     $value1 = (isset($value1)) ? 1 : 0;
     mysqli_query ($dbc, "UPDATE options SET value = '$value1' WHERE switch = 1 AND option_id = '$option_id'");
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае разумней получить список чекбоксов, если я правильно понял id группы чекбоксов записывается в поле switch. и сравнивать с полученными полями с сайта. если значение не пришло значит апдейтим в 0 если пришло 1.

как вариант, пожалуй идеальный в вашем случае заменить строку:

```
 echo '<input type="checkbox" name="parameter_value1['.$option_row_switch['option_id'].']" '.$cheked.' />';
```

на

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value="0" name="parameter_value1['.$option_row_switch['option_id'].']"/><input type="checkbox" name="parameter_value1['.$option_row_switch['option_id'].']" '.$cheked.' />';
```

т.е. hidden input с тем же именем перед checkbox'ом
и эту строчку

```
 $value1 = (isset($value1)) ? 1 : 0;
```

заменить на

```
$value1 = $value1 ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: нет в switch записывается разница для input, это нужно для различения - type="text" или type="checkbox" т.е. это вообще к делу не относиться. Параметр checked заносится в value

Comment: @ANTiK доплнил ответ.

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Потому что данные передаются когда установлена галочка.

Comment: это я понял, а как в бд занести параметр 0 для конкретного option_id?

Comment: Ничего не заносите, просто при выводе проверяйте если этот параметр.

Comment: прошу прощения, но ведь в этой строке и идет проверка при выводе
$cheked = ($option_row_switch['value'] == 1 ? 'checked' : '');
но так как в бд стоит 1 - он само собой покажет флажок, как после этого мне убрать с нее флажок?

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: если в строке value в бд прописана 1 - нам выдает checked для чекбокса, если 0 - соответственно - чекбокс остается пустым, так вот - каким образом поменять 1 на 0 в бд, учитывая что работать нужно не с одним чекбоксом а с несколькими

Answer (score 0):

Вот этот фрагмент что-то не нравится:

```
...
if (isset($_POST['parameter_value1']))
   {
    foreach($_POST['parameter_value1'] as $option_id => $value1)
    {
    ...
    }
```

Что вы здесь пытаетесь сделать? Переменная "$_POST['parameter_value1']" содержит одно значение - "true" или "false". Что вы пытаетесь вытащить из переменной в цикле "foreach"?

Comment: там массив значений, checkbox'ов то несколько

Comment: Вот это 1 чекбокс =)

    $cheked = ($option_row_switch['value'] == 1 ? 'checked' : '');
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="parameter_value1['.$option_row_switch['option_id'].']"'.$cheked.' />';

Comment: просто вырезал из кода:
$options_query_switch = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM options WHERE switch = '1' ORDER BY option_id");

  while ($option_row_switch = mysqli_fetch_array($options_query_switch))

  {
   $cheked = ($option_row_switch['value'] == 1 ? 'checked' : '');
   echo '<li>'.$option_row_switch['parameter'].' - <input type="checkbox" name="parameter_value1['.$option_row_switch['option_id'].']" '.$cheked.' /></li>';

  }